# Use python pandas to find consecutive same values string and sum duration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to pandas and I'm a bit confused about how to get my program to work. I found some solutions out there but they don't work properly in my case. I have the following dataframe:

```
#    Day           Date/Time                   Applicationname
1    2016-11-30    2016-11-30 01:27:47.722     comteslacoilswlauncher
2    2016-11-30    2016-11-30 01:27:52.679     comwhatsapp
3    2016-11-30    2016-11-30 01:27:57.690     comwhatsapp
4    2016-11-30    2016-11-30 01:28:02.690     screen_off
```

What I want to do is to group by the application name and have a start/end time for every grouped applicationname. For the start time I need the time of the first occurrence of the application - 2.5 seconds and for the end time I need the time of the last occurrence of the application + 2.5 seconds. In the case of only one occurrence I take the only time I have and I do -2.5 for the start and +2.5 for the end. For example:

```
#    Day         Start Date/Time          End Date/Time            Applicationname
1    2016-11-30  2016-11-30 01:27:45.222  2016-11-30 01:27:50.222  comteslacoilswlauncher
2    2016-11-30  2016-11-30 01:27:50.179  2016-11-30 01:28:00.190  comwhatsapp
4    2016-11-30  2016-11-30 01:28:00.190  2016-11-30 01:28:05.190  screen_off
```

Any hint on how do to it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From your solution example it seems like you want to group by day as well, even though you don't explicitly mention that. If that's the case you should be able to do something like this:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['Day', 'Applicationname'])
min_max = grouped.agg({'Date/Time': [np.min, np.max]})
```

Not tested :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def my_min(ser, delta=pd.Timedelta('2.5 second')):
    return ser.min() - delta

def my_max(ser, delta=pd.Timedelta('2.5 second')):
    return ser.max() + delta


df.groupby('Applicationname').agg({'Day':'first', 'Date/Time': [my_min, my_max]})
```

Result:

```
In [27]: df.groupby('Applicationname').agg({'Day':'first', 'Date/Time': [my_min, my_max]})
    ...:
Out[27]:
                              Day               Date/Time
                            first                  my_min                  my_max
Applicationname
comteslacoilswlauncher 2016-11-30 2016-11-30 01:27:45.222 2016-11-30 01:27:50.222
comwhatsapp            2016-11-30 2016-11-30 01:27:50.179 2016-11-30 01:28:00.190
screen_off             2016-11-30 2016-11-30 01:28:00.190 2016-11-30 01:28:05.190
```